# ¿Por qué me regresa este error Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Persona persona1 = new Persona();
        try{
            StringTokenizer st;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("entrada.txt"));
            String linea = br.readLine();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("datos.csv"));

            while(linea != null){
                st = new StringTokenizer(linea);
                persona1.setNombre(st.nextToken());
                persona1.setRFC(st.nextToken());
                persona1.setSueldoMensual(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                persona1.setPrimaVacacional(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));
                persona1.setGastosHospitalarios(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));
                persona1.setGastosFunerarios(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));
                persona1.setSGMM(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));
                persona1.setGastosHipotecarios(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));
                persona1.setDonativos(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));
                persona1.setAportacionRetiro(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));
                persona1.setTransporteEscolar(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));
                persona1.setNivelEducativo(st.nextToken());
                persona1.setColegiaturaTotal(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));

                pw.println(persona1.getNombre() + "," + persona1.getRFC() + "," + persona1.getSueldoMensual()
            + "," + persona1.getPrimaVacacional() + "," + persona1.getGastosHospitalarios() + "," + persona1.getGastosFunerarios()
            + "," + persona1.getSGMM() + "," + persona1.getGastosHipotecarios() + "," + persona1.getDonativos()
            + "," + persona1.getAportacionRetiro() + "," + persona1.getTransporteEscolar()
            + "," + persona1.getNivelEducativo() + "," + persona1.getColegiaturaTotal());
            }
            br.close();
            pw.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println("Ocurrio un error " + ex);
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println("Ocurrio un error " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Este es mi código, lo que hace es que recibe un documento .txt como entrada y tiene que regresar la información en un documento .csv. Al correr el programa me regresa el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>       at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
>       at Main.main(Main.java:26)

Answer (score 1):

La excepción que estás recibiendo, se debe a que:

> [NoSuchElementException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#hasMoreTokens%28%29) - if there are no more tokens in this
>   tokenizer's string.
>
> ---
>
> NoSuchElementException - si no hay más tokens en esta cadena tokenizer.

Por eso, antes de usar `nextToken()` es necesario preguntar por [`hasMoreTokens()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html). Para ello necesitas un `while` suplementario que abarque todo el bloque donde usas `nextToken()`:

```
    while(linea != null){

            st = new StringTokenizer(linea);

            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                persona1.setNombre(st.nextToken());
                persona1.setRFC(st.nextToken());
//etc
                persona1.setColegiaturaTotal(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));
                pw.println(persona1.getNombre() + "," + persona1.getRFC() + "," + ....
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu asumes ciegamente que tu archivo tiene el formato exacto que tu esperas. Modifica tu código en la siguiente manera y lo veras.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Persona persona1 = new Persona();
    String linea; // aquí
    int ln = 0;
    try{
        StringTokenizer st;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("entrada.txt"));
        linea = br.readLine(); // aquí
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("datos.csv"));

        while(linea != null){
            ln++; // nueva linea
            try{

            // código dentro del while sigue igual hasta:

            } catch(NoSuchElementException ex){
                System.out.println(String.format("NSE in %d: %s", ln, linea);
            }

            linea = br.readLine(); // probablemente quieres seguir leyendo.
        }
        br.close();
        pw.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.out.println("Ocurrio un error " + ex);
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Ocurrio un error " + ex);
    }
}
```

Al fin te conviene comprobar el formato de tu archivo linea por linea antes de decidir si lo quieres "tokenizar" y como.

Si puedes compartir un archivo de ejemplo se te puede sugerir una manera de validar el ingreso.